# Match range without duplicating

Tags: regex

I need to match 1/1 all the way through 4/48. 1/1,1/2,1/3 all the way through 1/48,2/1 through 2/48 ....3/1 through 3/48 and 4/1 through 4/48.... but having a hard time with the regex as it must not contain a comma at the end and not duplicate any thing that was already input.

```
^([1-4]\/([1-9]|[1-4][0-8]|[1-3][0-9]))[?\,]+$
```

Comment: Regular expressions may not be the right tool for this. Have you considered parsing the string yourself instead?

Comment: While I have not downvoted, as I read thru the comment thread below, I'll say this is not a well thought out question. For all the exceptions you have listed, you should compose a question that has an easy to use test suite of data that covers all of the cases you need to cover. Note that this doesn't mean we need to see all your data, but just enough of each unique type to compose a solution that will work for a small data set or your complete data set.

Comment: Also, rather than make people guess what tool you are using, you should state something like "I am coding this in python", AND you should include a tag for your language/tool. Finally, with sample data and expected output we might be able to suggest an alternate solution. As @PaulBenn says, RegEx might not be the right solution for this problem. Please read the [help] and especially [mcve] before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

To match numbers from `1` to `48`

- either `1` to `9` : `[1-9]`
- or `10` to `39` : `[1-3][0-9]`
- or `40` to `48` : `4[0-8]`

which gives

```
[1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-8]
```

Update from comments, the following regex

```
^(?:(?:^|,)[1-4]\/(?:[1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-8])(?=,|$))+$
```

About non-capturing group and lookaheads.

- a non-capturing group `(?:`..`)` is the same a group `(`..`)` except that it  can't be backreferenced, so it can be preferred to avoid to icrement the number of the backreference.
- a lookhead is not consumming which means that after the match the cursor in the input string doesn't move forward. for example after matching `(?:,)` the input cursor will after `,` while after matching `(?=,)` i.e. ensuring matches the following at input cursor position, the cursor position will still be before the `,`.

Comment: I have something similar but I dont have it working so that it avoids duplicates and does not contain comma at end of string..    ^([1-4]\/([1-9]|[1-4][0-8]|[1-3][0-9]))[?\,]+$

Comment: the order matters in your expression you have `[1-4][0-8]` which matches from 10 to 48 except 19,29,39 and then `[1-3][0-9]` which matches from 10 to 39

Comment: So far I have this:  ^([1-4]\/([1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-8])?,)[^,]+$

Comment: otherwise maybe i didn't understand exactly what you wanted to match if it's a fixed string, regex is not the tool.

Comment: Im very close but its still not matching certain things like 2/2 or duplicates are still matching   :   ^([1-4]\/([1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-8])[?\,])[^,]+$

Comment: I basically want it to match 1/48 through 4/48 and it can be as many with a comma delimiter. so it can be for example 1/1 or it can be 1/1,1/48,4/1 and i dont want them to duplicate like this 1/1,1/1

Comment: ok maybe the problem is do to the comma which is consumed twice, note the last lookahead instead of non capturing group `^(?:(?:^|,)[1-4]\/[1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-8](?=,|$))+$`

Comment: That works perfect thank you. Can you explain why you did it with non capturing groups though?

Comment: spoke too soon. Any reason 1/10 would'nt work? your regex seems to allow for it....

Comment: maybe just a mistake parenthesis missing around "1 to 48 expression" `^(?:(?:^|,)[1-4]\/(?:[1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-8])(?=,|$))+$`

Comment: yeah that works. the only thing is it accepts 1/1,1/1    is there something in regex that will not allow. something like a look behind?

Comment: so my final regex is ^((?:(?:^|,)[1-4]\/(?:[1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-8])(?=,|$))+)|((?:(?:^|,)([1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-8])(?=,|$))+)$ but this one allows for duplicates 1,1,2,2 or 1/1,1/1 anyway around that?

Comment: maybe `^(?:(?:^|,)((?:[1-4]\/)?(?:[1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-8]))(?=,|$)(?!.*(?<=,)\1(?=,|$)))+$` but may have poor performances because will check all pairs